# Euler Approximation for PDEs in vector format

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

Consider approximating solutions to a system of PDE of the form

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}f_i(x,t) = g_i(\dfrac{d}{dx} f_i(x,t), \dfrac{d}{dy} f_i(x,t), \dfrac{d}{dz} f_i(x,t), t), ~~~~~~~1\le i\le 3$$

with $g_i(x,t):\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ smooth and differentiable for all $(x,t)$.

Can we extend Euler's approach of approximating ODES with its derivative in one dimension to vectors. For example use a scheme such as

$$f_i^n(x,t) = f_i^{n-1}(x,t) +  \dfrac{d}{dt}f_i^{n-1}(x,t)* h$$ with h being a step size and $n$ being index of iteration (which we should take considerably smaller than time itself). How can we validate this approximation when solutions exist.

Comment: Please reduce the complexity. If the equations are decoupled, you do not need the index $i$. If you discretize the time parameter, then it does not appear in the value (here function) of the numerical approximation, it was replaced with the time index $n$.

Comment: this is a vector field F = (f_1,f_2,f_3) as functions of space and time. I dont want to discretize time because it is a smooth parameter. I feel like we only need a step size as in one dimsion. The question concern approximating a vector field at a point using its derivative at nearby point @LutzLehmann

Comment: There is no derivative in $x$ so it is not a PDE, right? Please state more clearly what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I changed it slightly. I want the mapping $g_i$ to map the derivatives of $f_i$ sorry. So yes I want it to be a pde. I feel like there is some generalization of 1d functions to function of three variables. Like if we start on a point on a surface that is changing in time we can approximate the surface at later time by using a Euler type method. The derivative on a surface is like a plane instead of a line I guess

Comment: Now you get a collection of unrelated PDE (write them with partial derivatives), but the right side is no longer Lipschitz, as the derivatives are unbounded operators. With space discretization you get the Lipschitz condition back, but the constant is very large, so you will need very small step sizes.